# Should the Firebase Admin SDK or Client handle token refresh?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to use firebase on my server for authentication and to provide an authentication experience for users that does not require pulling in firebase client side (for the moment).

A `/login` endpoint receives a username and password. Using `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword`, I am then returning the JWT token to the user. They can then use that in subsequent requests to my RESTful API as the bearer token.

The problem I'm struggling with is when that token expires (after an hour). Part of my flow when a request comes in that requires auth validation is verifying the token with `admin.auth().verifyIdToken`, and rejecting the request if it's no longer valid.

Is it correct to:

(1) provide the client with the `refresh` token as well in the initial sign-in so they can handle the rejection and then request a new JWT token?
(2) perform some action on the admin SDK to refresh the token on the user's behalf

In typical oauth scenarios I've worked with before, the client has always been responsible for refreshing the token, however I can't for the life of me figure out how to retrieve a new JWT token from that refresh token using either the `admin SDK` or the `firebase SDK`

I don't know if the firebase SDK that usually resides client side is handling this token refresh behind the scenes whenever it is used with `firebase.database`, etc. If i'm not using that client SDK, but instead using the token as a bearer token, can I have the client pass the refresh token for exchange of a new JWT token from the backend?

It's likely staring me right in the face, I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Authentication SDKs keep the refresh token in the client-side code, together with the ID token, and then use the former to mint a new ID token when needed (about 5 minutes before the current one expires).

Comment: OK. So since I can't really store the refresh token server side, if I provided it to the client they could use it in another restful call to request a new JWT token on failure of an earlier call. More akin to usual oauth flow.

Is there an SDK in admin or firebase SDK via node that would allow me to create a new JWT token after retrieving updated ID Token using the refresh token?

Comment: The ID token is already a JWT. Also see https://medium.com/@jwngr/demystifying-firebase-auth-tokens-e0c533ed330c: "ID tokens are short-lived JWTs"